# Отобразить содержимое поля во Views Drupal, если они не помечены меткой "Отображение"

Tags: веб-программирование, drupal, views

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться в следующем вопросе.
Есть тип материала **Текстовая страница** и поле **Документы** со следующими настройками: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также создано содержимое данного типа материала, где некоторые документы не помечены галочкой "**Отображение**":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести список не отображаемых документов. Пытаюсь сделать это с помощью модуля Views - не получается, выводятся документы, которые помечены галочкой "Отображение"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете разобраться с данной проблемой.

Comment: Если фильтры все удалить выводяться нужные документы?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала найди в базе таблицу где хранить поле. Найти можно по машинному полю. 
Дальше включи здесь отображение запроса который генерирует view

```
admin/structure/views/settings
```

Потом можно будет думать в чем проблема. А сейчас не понятно ничего с вопроса.